# Ampersand in mySQL query cuts off remaining value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Whenever I try to insert text that contains an ampersand (&), the ampersand and the remaining text that comes after it gets cut off.

```
$int = 0; $string = "You & I!";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` VALUES(?,?);";
$prepare = $connect -> prepare( $sql );
$prepare -> bind_param( "is", $int, $string );

// ETC.
```

Even if I escape (which I hate because it adds superfluous backstrokes to quotation marks):

```
$string = $connect -> real_escape_string( $string );
```

Only `You` will get inserted into the table. The field is set as `VARCHAR(100)`.

I cannot convert the ampersand into an HTML entity (`&amp;`) before hand because the database is also used by WIN32 apps. Getting the WIN32 apps to convert the entity to the normal character is something over which I have no control at the moment.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you write here the output from "$prepare->queryString" just after "bind_param" line

Comment: Should values be assigned before or after `bind_param()`?

Comment: There seems no problem about value assignment. This code seems correct. Please share the result of $prepare->queryString to see if your query is being built correctly.

Comment: I am working on it. Funny thing is; it doesn't do it in another script, despite having exactly the same code.

Comment: how long is your varchar field in the database?

Comment: As I said above, 100. I've tested putting the ampersand in various positions; the result is uncanny.

Comment: Can't use HTML entities. Data read by WIN32 app. Is anyone reading the OP?

Comment: What do you mean by "queryString"? That's not a mysqli_stmt property.

Comment: How did you check that the string is cut on *insertion*? Are you sure the problem is not related to the *rendering* of the query result?

Comment: @RandomSeed: you are right; that script was using XHR with a string query instead of FormData(). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know you can't use `&amp;` in your database, but if you try it, does it work? It's not clear how your PHP application is connecting to MySQL, but if it's RESTful then I suspect the ampersand is getting interpreted as a separator.

Comment: The field was cutting off because the data was being posted through XHR as a query string. Stupid me. Posting with a FormData() object solved the problem, of course. But, thanks anyway.